# Getting error "Can't locate HTML/TreeBuilder/XPath.pm in @INC "

Tags: perl, perl-module

Gettin below error while running my perl file

`Can't locate HTML/TreeBuilder/XPath.pm in @INC (@INC contains: C:/Perl/lib C:/Pe
rl/site/lib .) at display.pl line 4.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at display.pl line 4.`

HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath module(0.14) is installed. From command line when i run command

```
 perl -e HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath it doesn't give any error.
```

when i run from command line perldoc -l HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath gives below error:

```
No documentation found for "HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath".
```

My perl version is 5.8.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First cross check does this module is really installed ? I think it is not installed, install it from `cpan`.